# How can I read a dictionary with a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I read a list inside a dictionary and try to change string numbers to digits? For example:

```
obj = {'azul':'4','rojo':[{'rojo_a':'1','rojo_b':'2'}],'amarillo':'xxx','naranja':[{'naranja_1':'1','naranja_2':'2'}]}
```

I use this to change dictionary number strings to integers:

```
{k:int(v) if v.isdigit() else v for k,v in obj.items()}
```

But it doesn't work, so I was trying something like this:

```
for objs in obj:
if objs.isdigit():
    k:int(v)
else:
    for k,v in objs.items():
        print k
```

But this fails as well.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you want the output dict to look like, given your input?

Comment: I think you want `{k:int(v) if isinstance(v, str) and v.isdigit() else v for k,v in obj.items()}`

Comment: @Lol4t0 ... I think they want the behaviour to recurse into subdicts and sublists...

Comment: @JoranBeasley sure but I believe problem is not in recursion, and it is just skipped for simplicity and not because OP can't implement it.

Answer (score 4):

this seems like a good problem for recursion

```
obj = {'azul':'4','rojo':[{'rojo_a':'1','rojo_b':'2'}],'amarillo':'xxx','naranja':[{'naranja_1':'1','naranja_2':'2'}]}
def fix_ints(obj):
    if isinstance(obj,basestring):
        try:
            return int(obj)
        except ValueError:
            print "I cant Make %r an int"%obj
            return obj
    elif isinstance(obj,(list,tuple)):
        return [fix_ints(item) for item in obj]
    elif isinstance(obj,dict):
        return dict((key,fix_ints(value)) for key,value in obj.items())
    else:
        print "I have no idea what to do with %r"%obj

new_obj = fix_ints(obj)
print new_obj
```

note that python does not support tail recursion so if this data structure goes very deep (greater than 1k levels of nesting) then recursion may not be appropriate ...

of coarse you can also do silly string tricks with it

```
import json,re
new_obj = json.loads(re.sub("\"(\d+)\"","\\1",json.dumps(obj)))
```

(although really you should do it like i do in my first exzample ... this second method is really just for fun)

Comment: I just finished my version of the same recursion but you were faster... xP

Comment: Returns `None` if there is `dict` inside `dict` inside one of those lists though! I'd still go for my solution :p Although I must admit that yours is quite elegant, and does the job in this context.

Comment: jajaja wow amazin, but i got the problem that if i have an obj with False it become null or float like 4.00 become none too.. Thanks Joran Beasley

Comment: @JorgeD.Jesus ... no te entiendo che... ejemplo obj por favor ?

Comment: Antes que nada se le agradece su tiempo sr.. y con esto he aprendido un poco mas.. le explico, recibire un string el cual debo convertir a dicionario una vez convertido a diccionarioa debia convertir todos los numeros que este tuviera dentro a int.. pero resulta que algunos valores tales como False se convertian en 'none' al imprimir el dictionary..

Comment: no no presenta un objecto q no funciona correctamente con este solucion

Answer (score 0):

String to number:

```
def int_it(obj):
    if obj.isdigit():
        obj = int(obj)

    return obj
```

Dict to number (regardless of the number of nested dicts or lists):

```
class Convert(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            self.handle_dict(obj)

    def handle_dict(self, obj):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if isinstance(value, str) and value.isdigit():
                self.obj[key] = int_it(value)

            elif isinstance(obj[key], list):
                ins = HandleList(obj[key])
                self.obj[key] = ins.obj

            elif isinstance(obj[key], dict):
                ins = Convert(obj.items())
                self.obj[key] = ins.obj

        return obj
```

List to numbers, regardless of the number of nested lists or dicts.

```
class HandleList(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        self.handle_list(obj)

    def handle_list(self, obj):
        for index, item in enumerate(obj):
            if isinstance(item, list):
                obj.index(index, [HandleList(val).obj for val in item])

            elif isinstance(item, str):
                obj.index(index, int_it(item))

            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                Convert(item)

        return obj


output = Convert(values)

print(output.obj)
```

Returns:

```
{
   'amarillo': 'xxx', 
   'naranja': [{'naranja_1': 1, 'naranja_2': 2}], 
   'rojo': [{'rojo_b': 2, 'rojo_a': 1}], 
   'azul': 4
 }
```

Given the input:

```
values = {
   'azul':'4',
   'rojo': [
            {'rojo_a':'1',
             'rojo_b':'2'
            }
           ],
   'amarillo':'xxx',
   'naranja': [
               {'naranja_1':'1',
                'naranja_2':'2'
               }
              ]
   }
```